# vectorized inputs for if statements with several value changes (enabling a function to be used with apply)

Tags: r, function, if-statement, package, apply

I am trying to apply a function from a package to certain columns of my dataframe.
The package is linked [here](https://cran.r-project.org/package=jalcal).

However, the author of the package used simple if statements, which won't let me use apply function, because of vectorized conditions. My problem is fixing [this function](https://github.com/jalilian/jalcal/blob/main/R/jal2greg.R) specifically, so that I can use it in an apply function.

Mainly there are 4 if statements that need addressing:

1:

```
if (month < 1 | month > 12)
    stop("month is outside the range 1-12")
  if (day < 1 | day > 31)
    stop("day is outside the range 1-31")
```

2:

```
    if (month < 7)
      {
        days <- days + 31 * (month -1 )
      } else{
        days <- days + 186 + 30 * (month - 7)
      }
```

3:

```
if (days > 36524)
  {
    days <- days - 1
    gyear <- gyear + 100 * (days %/% 36524)
    days <- days %% 36524
    if (days >= 365)
      days <- days + 1
  }
```

4:

```
  if (days > 365)
  {
    gyear <- gyear + ((days - 1) %/% 365)
    days <- (days - 1) %% 365
  }
```

Now I know I can fix some of them with simple ifelse statements, but I have seen people avoiding assigning variables inside an ifelse statement and I prefer to use a general approach to fix this. Also, dplyr's case_when cannot be generally applied as well.
Can anyone kindly help me solve this problem in a general relatively efficient way?

edit-
As per MrFlick's comment, this is how I intend to use the function
I have the original dates in my dataframe in months (summed as total months)

```
convert_date_to_greg <- function(x){
  year = floor(as.numeric(x)/12)
  month = (as.numeric(x)%%12)+1
  day = 1 
  ifelse(is.na(x)==FALSE,return(jal2greg(year,month,day,asDate = T)),return(NA))
}

greg_convert <- lapply(date_sorted_df[,date_column_indices],
                   FUN=convert_date_to_greg)
```

This is a sample input:

```
df<- data.frame(date_1=c(16735,16234,17123,16123), date_2=c(16352,16352,16666,17124))
```

However, using apply, I will see the following error message:

> the condition has length > 1

Comment: Maybe just try wrapping the function in `Vectorize()`? It's unclear exactly how you want to call this function. It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As per your comment, how I intend to use it and a sample is provided. @MrFlick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply()` type functions are for vectorized functions; they are not meant to be used with functions like this. You'll probably need to fix the function or use a solution other than `apply()`.

I'd suggest fixing the function (R code should be vectorized when possible). For 1, you'll just want to check if any inputs are invalid. For 2-4, `ifelse()` will be helpful.

For 1:

```
if (sum(month < 1 | month > 12) != 0) { stop("a month is outside the range 1-12") }
if (sum(day < 1 | day > 31) != 0) { stop("a day is outside the range 1-31") }
```

For 2:

```
days <- ifelse(month < 7, days + 31 * (month -1 ), days + 186 + 30 * (month - 7))
```

For 3:

```
days <- days - 1
gyear <- gyear + 100 * (days %/% 36524)
days <- days %% 36524
days <- ifelse(days >= 365, days <- days + 1, days)
```

For 4:

```
gyear <- ifelse(days > 365, gyear + ((days - 1) %/% 365, gyear)
days  <- ifelse(days > 365, (days - 1) %% 365, days)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I apologize as I mis-copied the code in section 3 and missed the if statement at the top, however, I think I got the gist of it. Thanks again.